# How to set different length for different borderline of a box using tcolorbox?

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox, books, examples

I would like to create box of example using tcolorbox as the picture below:

[image]

and so far this what i got

[image]

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{example}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    left=0.5em,right=0pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,    
    attach title to upper={},
    coltitle={black},
    fonttitle={\bfseries},
    title={EXAMPLE \thetcbcounter\ },
    sharp corners,
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    borderline north={1pt}{0pt}{gray},
    borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{blue},
    borderline south={1pt}{0pt}{red},
    colback={white},
    #1
    }
\newcommand\solution{\par\textsf\bfseries{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{SOLUTION }}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{example}
        \lipsum[2]
        \solution \lipsum[4]
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

I want the length of borderline north as long as the "example 0.1" text and the length of borderline south just arbitrary horizontal line.

**Could someone please improve my code to create the same picture as I post on top. Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use a `boxed title`, there's no node `title` to be used as reference. Therefore I've changed your style to use a `boxed title` an inserted a `hspace` before upper part instead of `attach title to upper` option. This way has been possible to draw the line over title box. The line below the box is added with a `overlay` command.

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{example}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    left=0.5em, right=0pt, top=1pt, bottom=1pt,    
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight},
     boxed title style={%
        empty,
        right=0pt,
        frame code={\draw[line width=1pt, gray] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);}},
    before upper=\hspace{\tcboxedtitlewidth},
     colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle={black},
    colback={white},
    fonttitle={\bfseries},
    title={EXAMPLE \thetcbcounter\ },
    sharp corners,
    frame hidden,
    boxrule=0pt,
    borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{blue},
     overlay unbroken and last={%
        \draw[line width=1pt, red] (frame.south west)   -- ++(0:1cm);},
    #1
    }
\newcommand\solution{\par\textsf\bfseries{\textbf{\textcolor{black}{SOLUTION }}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{example}
        \lipsum[2]
        \solution \lipsum[4]
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks @Ignasi, thats exactly what i was looking for. btw if you dont mind, i have another question. What to do if i want to fill the boxed title with some color?

Comment: Comment `empty` inside `boxed title style` and change `colbacktitle` to something not `white`.

Comment: oh i see, thx @Ignasi!